# Changing the meta_query of the main query based on custom query_vars and using pre_get_posts

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-query, pre-get-posts

I've registered custom rewrite rules and `query_vars` to use for displaying a list of events based on ISO date format. For example when a user requests the URL, `http://site.com/by-date/2013-04-04/`, my `query_var` is the date portion and I'd like to display a list of events who's `meta_key` of `_event_scheduled_date` equals the ISO date value in the `query_var`.

Whenever I try the following code to modify the `$query` in `pre_get_posts` WordPress initiates a 404 and no posts are queried. I've been able to use `pre_get_posts` to manipulate other taxonomy listings and archive pages, but have yet been able to get it to work correctly with the custom `query_var` I've created.

```
function rewrite_rule_by_date() {
    add_rewrite_rule('(by\-date)/([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&event_date=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_rule_by_date' );

function query_var_by_date() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%event_date%', '([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})');
}
add_action( 'init', 'query_var_by_date' );

function custom_event_query( $query ) {
    if (  is_page( 'by-date' ) && get_query_var( 'event_date' ) && is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'event' );
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_event_scheduled_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'post_per_page', -1 );

        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => '_event_scheduled_date',
                'value' => get_query_var( 'event_date' ),
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_event_query' );
```

Comment: @s_ha_dum, thanks for the edit. I started to use code syntax like you did, but wasn't sure if it was over kill.

Comment: Is this code within a class? Saw a $this reference and wanted to be sure.

Comment: It was, but I took the snippet out removing keywords and forgot to remove references to &$this. Did that so I could post it here for the same of simplicity.

Comment: Did you flush your rewrite rules? Did you try the plugin "Rewrite Rules Inspector" to check if the rule works?

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: Does get_query_var( 'event_date' ) actually get any value?

Comment: Indeed it does. Returns the value from the custom query_var. In fact when I var_dump() the $query object itself you can see it plus the meta_query being set.

Comment: So to confirm, you say the query does actually get set, but it's not sticking?

Comment: Correct. When I request the page and have the query dumped in the main query to see if the SQL is set in $wp_query->request there is nothing.

Comment: Just double checking - have you added your **event_date** query var to the "allowed" query vars via the **query_vars** hook?

Comment: @AndyAdams, correctomundo sir.

Comment: I've accepted the answer given by @birgire -- works as expected. Thanks to everyone who spent time on this and offered feedback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of trying to display all the matching events on your `by-date` page, you could try to display through `?post_type=event` like this:

```
function rewrite_rule_by_date() {
    add_rewrite_rule('by\-date/([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})$', 'index.php?post_type=event&event_date=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_rule_by_date' );

function query_var_by_date() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%event_date%', '([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})');
}
add_action( 'init', 'query_var_by_date' );

function custom_event_query( $query ) {
    if ( get_query_var( 'event_date' ) && is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'event' );
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_event_scheduled_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'post_per_page', -1 );

        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => '_event_scheduled_date',
                'value' => get_query_var( 'event_date' ),
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_event_query' );
```

This works on my Wordpress `3.5.1` install with the default Twenty Twelve theme, with url like this one:

```
http://example.com/by-date/2013-04-04/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's always the minor details that I overlook. Cheers!